# load a python trained xgboost in c++ api, the predict result is empty

Tags: python, c++, xgboost

i am training a 13 category classification on python xgboost, my feature dim is 3207, the model is saved after python xgbsoot training, and i checked some case, the result is normal.
but when i load the model in c++ xgboost， and do predict, the result is nothing. here is my c++ code demo:

```
  BoosterHandle booster_ = nullptr;
  std::cout << "befor:" << booster_ << std::endl;
  if (XGBoosterCreate(NULL, 0, &booster_) == 0 &&
       XGBoosterLoadModel(booster_, model_path.c_str()) == 0) {
    LOG(INFO) << "load xgboost model success !";
  } else {
    LOG(ERROR) << "load xgboost model error !";
    booster_ = NULL;
  }

  // build Dmatrix data, two fake example, the expect predict label is 1, prob = 0.927.
  float d_values[2][3207] = {0};
  d_values[0][0] = 1.0;
  d_values[0][8] = 1.0;
  d_values[0][6] = 1.0;
  d_values[0][14] = 1.0;
  d_values[1][0] = 1.0;
  d_values[1][8] = 1.0;
  d_values[1][6] = 1.0;
  d_values[1][14] = 1.0;
  std::cout <<"predict:" << booster_ << std::endl;
  int r = XGDMatrixCreateFromMat(&d_values[0][0], 2, 3207, 0.0, &data);
  if (r != 0) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "build DMatrix failed!!";
  }
  std::cout <<"r=" << r << std::endl;
  const float* out;
  uint64_t len;
  auto ret = XGBoosterPredict(booster_, data, 0, 0, &len, &out);
  if (ret < 0) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "xgboost inference error !";
    return -1;
  }
  std::cout << "len=" << len << std::endl;
  XGDMatrixFree(data);
  return 0;
```

the result is:

```
  r=0
  len=0
```

everty step in this demo , the return status code equal 0，but the final len=0， what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason，my python xgboost is trained anaconda， the xgboost is different from c++ xgboost source code version.